# php not functioning inside html file but works outside

Tags: php, html, mysql, wamp, meekro

I have been following the php tutorial [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/learn-build-php-crash-course/)

**CODE**

Here is my html file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

        <link rel=”stylesheet” type=”text/css” href=”style.css”>

        <form action="postForm.php" method="post">

        <TextArea name="microBlog" id="microBlog" cols="30" rows=“10"></TextArea>  

        <input type="submit">          

        </form>

    </head>

    <body>

        <?php          

            require_once 'meekrodb.2.3.class.php';          
            DB::$user = 'root';          
            DB::$password = '';          
            DB::$dbName = 'MicroBlog';          
            $results = DB::query("SELECT post FROM MicroBlog");          
            foreach ($results as $row){                  

                echo "<div class='microBlog'>" . $row['post'] . "</div>";          
            }          

        ?>  


    </body>

    </html>
```

This yields the following:

[image]

However if I copy the php code into a new postForm.php file and click "Submit" (as you can see the action is postForm.php), it works.

I get my blank screen with 3 words (from the database).

The problem is it is a brand new blank page and I do not want that.

**PROBLEM**

Why is it that the code works outside the html file, but not inside the html file. Why do I get `".row['post']."";} ?>` when inside the html file but I get perfect output when the php exists in its own php file?

There is clearly nothing wrong with the code, so what could it be?

It really confuses me. Thanks for any answers.

Comment: what is your file extension ?

Comment: It is a .html file. When I set an action to open a separate .php file with the same php code, it suddenly works. But the code is the same!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your file extension `.html` into `.php` or `.phtml`. It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing a php code inside html file. html file doesn't evaluate php code.change the extension of file to **.php** instead of **.html** by doing so you write both html and php code inside that file.

Answer (score 0):

**Reason:** 1. An html file does not support php scripts inside it and thus anything written will not be executed and will only be treated as an html markup.

**Solution:** 
1. Just save the .html file as .php file and you are done!(very simple).For example if your file name is index.html, just save it as index.php and all the php scripts inside will be executed.

**index.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

        <link rel=”stylesheet” type=”text/css” href=”style.css”>

        <form action="postForm.php" method="post">

        <textArea name="microBlog" id="microBlog" cols="30" rows=“10"></textArea>  

        <input type="submit">          

        </form>

    </head>

    <body>

        <?php          

            require_once 'meekrodb.2.3.class.php';          
            DB::$user = 'root';          
            DB::$password = '';          
            DB::$dbName = 'MicroBlog';          
            $results = DB::query("SELECT post FROM MicroBlog");          
            foreach ($results as $row){                  

                echo "<div class='microBlog'>" . $row['post'] . "</div>";          
            }          

        ?>  


    </body>

    </html>
```